# How you can make a 3D mask in the UI so that it is displayed correctly. Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, shader

I have a leaderboard where I display a player's information and their profile picture.
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbzXW.png)

The picture (this is the cat's head on the left) was made in 3D so that I could animate it for different skins. I made a mask for the scroll view and it works fine, as you can see in the picture above.
Under the rating I want to show the player’s place and his skin.[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkf5k.png) .


But in order for his skin to be displayed, I need to put the same max in this place as on the scroll view (because the skins have the same shaders and it won’t be drawn without stencil ref =1) But when I put the shader in that place that makes the ref = 1, then other objects start to be drawn along with the one I need (since the scroll view goes far down).
[picture3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxuB2.png)


I tried to solve this in different ways, but I came to the conclusion that since the objects have the same material, they will always be drawn together, regardless of what masks and comparisons I make in the shader.

My shader mask:

```
Shader "Custom/UIMaskFor3D"
{
    Properties
    {
        [IntRange] _StencilComp ("Stencil Comparison", Range(1,8)) = 1
        [IntRange] _Stencil ("Stencil ID", Range(0,255)) = 0
        [IntRange] _StencilOp ("Stencil Operation", Range(0,7))=2
        _StencilWriteMask ("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
        _StencilReadMask ("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255
        _ColorMask ("Color Mask", Float) = 15

    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "Queue"="Geometry-1" }
        Blend Zero One
        ZWrite Off
        
        Pass {
            Stencil
            {
                Ref [_Stencil]
                Comp [_StencilComp]
                Pass [_StencilOp]
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

My shader for skin:

```
Shader "Unlit/Transparent" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}

        [IntRange] _StencilComp ("Stencil Comparison", Range(1,8)) = 1
        [IntRange] _Stencil ("Stencil ID", Range(0,255)) = 1
        [IntRange] _StencilOp ("Stencil Operation", Range(0,7))=0


        _StencilWriteMask ("Stencil Write Mask", Range(0,255)) = 255.000000
        _StencilReadMask ("Stencil Read Mask", Range(0,255)) = 255.000000
        _ColorMask ("Color Mask", Float) = 15
    }
    
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        LOD 100
    
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    
        Stencil{
            Ref [_Stencil]
            ReadMask [_StencilReadMask]
            WriteMask [_StencilWriteMask]
            Comp Equal
        }

        Pass {
           
        
            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma target 2.0
                #pragma multi_compile_fog
    
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"
    
                struct appdata_t {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                    UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
                };
    
                struct v2f {
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                    UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
                };
    
                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;
    
                v2f vert (appdata_t v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                    UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                    return o;
                }
    
                fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                    return col;
                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```